# How can a react-native app save a variable after the app is turned off?

Tags: react-native

I want to make an app remember some data that a user puts in even after he turns off the phone (like auto-login). How can this be done in React Native? Or which libraries/components should I research?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do something like auto-login you should probably be using [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) so that you can store user credentials in the keychain on the device in a more secure way.

If you are looking to store a particular application state or other non sensitive data you could use [react-native-simple-store](https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store) which provides a really simple wrapper around [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#content) and takes care of the boilerplate JSON.stringify/JSON.parse that you need to do for objects and arrays.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can use flux stores, async store to store the current state in store, and re-route based on the store

can use componentWillMount mixing for setting up state before rendering view. for e.g.:

```
componentWillMount() {
    LocalStorage.bootstrap(() => this.setState({bootstrapped: true}));
},
```

you can refer https://github.com/brentvatne/flux-util/blob/master/lib/flux-util.js for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AsyncStorage bundled with react-native. It creates key value pairs

`AsyncStorage.setItem("key", "value").done()     // both key and value have to be strings`
`AsyncStorage.getItem("key").then((value) =>{}).done()`

You can check the documentation for more options
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#content

Comment: Note that this is unencrypted and shouldn't be used for sensitive user data